Reportlab side bar
I'm trying to create a planner using report lab. The idea is to have tabs on the left-hand side with the months. But for some reason, I am able to get the font vertically or create rectangles to have the months. Instead, I have a bunch of squares that I can't change the sizes vertically.
def add_side_tabs(c, height):
    months= [
        "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
        "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"
    ]
    
    tab_width = 35
    tab_height = 40
    tab_start_x = 10
    tab_start_y = height - 300
    
    for i, months in enumerate(months):
        tab_y = tab_start_y - (i * (tab_height + 2))
        
        c.setFillColor(colors.lightgrey)
        c.setStrokeColor(colors.black)
        c.rect(tab_start_x, tab_y, tab_width, -tab_width, fill=1)
        #c.rect(10, height-300, 30, -30, fill=1)
        c.saveState()
        c.translate(150 + 15,  - (100))
        c.rotate(90)
        c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 10)
        c.setFillColor(colors.black)
        c.drawCentredString(0,0, months)
        c.restoreState()

How can I fix it in a way that I can adjust the rect and have the month names appear vertically?

Answer is
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def add_side_tabs(c, height):
    months = [
        "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
        "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"
    ]
    
    # Tab dimensions and placement
    tab_width = 35
    tab_height = 40
    tab_start_x = 10
    tab_start_y = height - 50  # Start from the top, leaving some margin

    for i, month in enumerate(months):
        tab_y = tab_start_y - (i * (tab_height + 5))  # Space between tabs
        
        # Draw rectangle for each tab
        c.setFillColor(colors.lightgrey)
        c.setStrokeColor(colors.black)
        c.rect(tab_start_x, tab_y - tab_height, tab_width, tab_height, fill=1)
        
        # Add rotated text inside the tab
        c.saveState()
        c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 10)
        c.setFillColor(colors.black)
        # Translate to the center of the tab
        c.translate(tab_start_x + (tab_width / 2), tab_y - (tab_height / 2))
        c.rotate(90)  # Rotate text for vertical alignment
        c.drawCentredString(0, 0, month)
        c.restoreState()

# Create the PDF and test
file_name = "planner_with_tabs.pdf"
pdf = canvas.Canvas(file_name, pagesize=(595, 842))  # A4 size (width x height)
add_side_tabs(pdf, height=842)  # Pass the page height
pdf.save()

Key Fixes:

Adjust the rect dimensions (tab_height and tab_width) properly
Ensure the text is rotated and placed in alignment with the tabs.
Use c.rotate(90) and proper translation logic for vertical text inside the tabs

